Force Markdown text to be very small
I wish to add some frontmatter to my Markdown file, which then uses Pandoc and the Eisvogel template to generate separate sections of a PDF document.
The build script I use is as follows:
#!/bin/sh
DATE=$(date "+%d %B %Y")
time -p pandoc \
    -s $(cat includes-lg.txt) \
    -o "sample.pdf" \
    -M date="$DATE" \
    --from markdown \
    --toc \
    --toc-depth 2 \
    --filter=pandoc-latex-environment \
    --filter=pandoc-latex-unlisted \
    --template "eisvogel.tex" \
    --number-sections \
    --listings

I make a call to an includes.txt file which contains the following items:
L0.md
L1.md
L2.md
L3.md

I can add additional Markdown files as needed to this includes.txt file. Files L1.md and L2.md and so on contain basic Markdown. The pandoc script joins them together into a single PDF document.
The file L0.md contains frontmatter which needs to be in 8pt font rather than the standard 12pt. However, the file L0.md also contains the preamble I use for generating the final PDF. This preamble is what eisvogel requires for generating the final output of all the files.
Here is my sample preamble at the top of L0.md.
---
title: "Test Output"
titlepage: true
subtitle: "Sample Code"
author: Anonymous
date: "2024-05-23"
subject: "Sample Output"
keywords: [Markdown, Pandoc, Eisvogel]
lang: "en"
geometry: "left=0.75in,right=0.75in,top=1.0in,bottom=1.0in"
footer-left: "Copyright"
footer-center: 
footer-right: 
header-left:
header-right: "Test"
toc: true
toc-own-page: true
listings-disable-line-numbers: true
listings-no-page-break: true
code-block-font-size: \small
header-includes:

<ad nauseum>
...

My question is:
Is there a simple way to edit the contents of the L0.md file and make portions (if not all) of the text much smaller, i.e., 8pt font rather than the 12pt font?
I know the eisvogel.tex template does support \frontmatter, \mainmatter, and \endmatter, but I am having a hard time getting this to work with Markdown. Then, getting the frontmatter to have a different fontsize is a tough nut to crack.
Likewise, can I edit my headers and footers and make their font smaller as well, using 8pt?
Thanks in advance.
Update:
I think I figured it out. I added the following LaTeX code to my frontmatter text and that seems to have solved the issue, at least with the frontmatter text.
\begin{footnotesize}
This document is produced by Company X.

This document or any part thereof may not be reproduced or transmitted in any form under penalty of law, without the prior written permission of Company X. 
\end{footnotesize}

This changes the font size to 8pt and appears to be an acceptable solution.

well in latex you can use \tiny or \footnotesize or \small for example, but I don't know how you tell pandoc to add that at the right place

\scriptsize ? In this kind of questions is hard guess what are you doing really and therefore propose appropriate solutions. Please add a minimal working example (MWE) and point there what exatly  should change.

Please rad the description of the latex3 tag and use it only, when it actually applies

Markdown itself does not have a specific syntax for changing font size, but it can include HTML or LaTeX syntax depending on what the desired goal is: getting a web page (off topic here) or a PDF (though LaTeX).
Also, Quarto markdown allow specify the font size in the header, so you can do something like:
---
fontsize: 8pt
format: pdf
---

Foo *foo*
\huge foo *foo* 
\normalsize foo *foo*  \mbox{\fontsize{40}{50}\selectfont foo *foo*}
foo *foo*

And obtain ( by default, via xelatex) this:

Note that the the giant *foo* is not in cursive because is not markdown text, but pure LaTeX text inside a LaTeX command argument, whereas text after LaTeX commands without arguments (as \huge) is again markdown text. The commands of the example and the comments are just examples. Any basic LaTeX tutorial explain how to set many others standard font sizes. See for instance What point (pt) font size are \Large etc.?
